# Adding Collapsible functions using Material-UI Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, drawer

I was able to setup the Drawer working in my application. One feature I found missing in the default is the collapsible option, where sections are nested. an example is Mail which would have `inbox, sent, outbox,` etc.

I want it to look something like this:

`Mail
   Inbox
   Sent
   Outbox`

How can I do this? This file is shared across the demos.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';
import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import ReportIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Report';

export const mailFolderListItems = (
    <div>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <InboxIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <StarIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <SendIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Send mail" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <DraftsIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </ListItem>
    </div>
);

export const otherMailFolderListItems = (
    <div>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <MailIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="All mail" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <DeleteIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <ReportIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
        </ListItem>
    </div>
);

//
```

Comment: Hi kehinde. It is not strictly mandatory for question authors to reply to, vote on, or accept answers, but the community would collapse if no-one did so. I wonder if you would examine the answer below, and respond to that helpful person in some fashion?

Comment: Hi Kehinde. Are you seeing my messages? You appear to have signed in since I posted the above.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the "Nested List" demo: https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/#nested-list

```
// ...
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
// ...

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  state = { open: true };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List
          component="nav"
          subheader={<ListSubheader component="div">Nested List Items</ListSubheader>}
        >
          {/* ... */}
          <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <InboxIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText inset primary="Inbox" />
            {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <StarBorder />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText inset primary="Starred" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```